# Add semi transparent gray layer on top of background color

Tags: html, css

I have a Table containing many TDs. Each TD can has different background color (i.e.: yellow, red, green. etc) But unknown in advance.

I want to add a semi-transparent gray layer on top of some of the TD

So that ...

The TD with yellow background will become dark yellow.

The TD with red background will become dark red
...

and the text inside TD remains the same (black)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite easy to do, just use an inset `box-shadow`:

```
.selectedTD{
    box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 500px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```css
div {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
  color: white;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div>This has a darker background because of an inset box-shadow</div>
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/u5dbbo5n/)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using a [linear gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) to act as a sort of filter for the background-color:

```css
.filtered {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 0, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) 100%);
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color: red">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div style="background-color: orange">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div style="background-color: yellow">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div style="background-color: green">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div style="background-color: blue">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div style="background-color: purple">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<br>
<div class="filtered" style="background-color: red">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div class="filtered" style="background-color: orange">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div class="filtered" style="background-color: yellow">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div class="filtered" style="background-color: green">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div class="filtered" style="background-color: blue">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
<div class="filtered" style="background-color: purple">
  lorem ipsum
</div>
```

Alternatively, use the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) rule in CSS although it will affect the foreground as well as the background.

Comment: Interesting answer, didn't think about doing it that way :D The one advantage box shadow has over doing it like this, is that it has a little better browser support.

Comment: @JacobGray, if you need browser support, use an image.

Answer (score 0):

You can put a FILTER on the color. This might be more elegant than using an inset box-shadow.

You can read an excellent tutorial on filters here: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/filter/

In your case, you would be using the **brightness** filter to change each individual color. Of course, you can use a JavaScript function to do so dynamically if you please.

Comment: Box shadows are beautiful :P The problem with using a filter is demonstrated here http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/EVOmEa. The content of the div also is darkened, not just the background, making the text look bad. Filters also have bad support http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: Fair enough, I just thought it would be easier to implement. :)