# SASS - Use color darken without using a color

Tags: colors, sass

Pretty sure this isn't possible but thought I would ask

I have a jsfiddle here - https://jsfiddle.net/uprfxhL9/1/

I can use SASS's darken to change a color using the color and a percentage.

I'm actual working with a button where the color is set in CMS so I don't know the color in the CSS.

It it possible someway to say whatever the color is darken it by a percentage and not actual have the color to darken in the function.

```
    $base-color: #f22727;

    .btn{  
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 20px;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        background-color: $base-color; 
    }

    .one{ 
        &:hover{
            background-color: darken($base-color, 20%);
        }
    }

It worked a lot for me thanx!! I've just settle down the darken value to 
15%, so that it would come more lighter. Look at my codes below:

    .my-class {
        background: darken($color-base, 15%);
         padding: 20px;
```

Comment: Exactly what color do you think should be darkened here?

Comment: The color of the button, but I don't know this color in the css as it's set in the CMS and added as an inline css style

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no, it isn't possible.
However, you could darken it with a box-shadow, like posted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33633219/3285730):

```
box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 500px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

This renders the exact same effect, as you can see [in this codepen](http://codepen.io/Jacob-Gray/pen/epQbMV).

If the .btn doesn't have any content, or you want to use multiple elements, you could use a filter:

```
  -webkit-filter: brightness(.5);
  filter: brightness(.5);
```

However, filters don't have the best support (They are not supported in IE at all)